# Saving Dockerfile ENV variables for future use

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I want to save `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that are set in a Dockerfile to  .bashrc for future use.
However, it looks like `PATH` is saved correctly but not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
For example, take the following simple Dockerfile that saves these variables to temporary files:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-centos7 AS devel
ENV PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/bin:$PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RUN touch mylibpath && \
    touch mybinpath && \
    echo $PATH >> mybinpath && \
    echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH >> mylibpath
```

The result is `PATH` has correct values while `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is blank as shown below.
BUT if I renamed the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to something like `ALD_LIBRARY_PATH` it prints correct values.
What am I missing ?

```
================Before renaming =======================

$ sudo docker build --no-cache -t dshawul/acecast:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-centos7 AS devel
 ---> 96c10ed77499
Step 2/4 : ENV PATH /opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in 2e3cf9a3ad64
 ---> cd56324327ab
Removing intermediate container 2e3cf9a3ad64
Step 3/4 : ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 ---> Running in d228c9421efc
 ---> 43c2d0043ff5
Removing intermediate container d228c9421efc
Step 4/4 : RUN touch mylibpath &&     touch mybinpath &&     echo $PATH >> mybinpath &&     echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH >> mylibpath
 ---> Running in 52ba4a205815
 ---> e9aede6ab347
Removing intermediate container 52ba4a205815
Successfully built e9aede6ab347
Successfully tagged dshawul/acecast:latest

$ sudo docker run -it dshawul/acecast:latest
[root@efdfdcf693d9 /]# cat mybinpath
/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[root@efdfdcf693d9 /]# cat mylibpath

[root@efdfdcf693d9 /]# exit
exit

==================After renaming ==============================

$ sudo docker build --no-cache -t dshawul/acecast:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-centos7 AS devel
 ---> 96c10ed77499
Step 2/4 : ENV PATH /opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in 3628b77881b4
 ---> c98fc82bba60
Removing intermediate container 3628b77881b4
Step 3/4 : ENV ALD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/lib:$ALD_LIBRARY_PATH
 ---> Running in 5eea6a5675c0
 ---> 7da3fb187682
Removing intermediate container 5eea6a5675c0
Step 4/4 : RUN touch mylibpath &&     touch mybinpath &&     echo $PATH >> mybinpath &&     echo $ALD_LIBRARY_PATH >> mylibpath
 ---> Running in ebdfdd5e3762
 ---> c175b1fbd2c1
Removing intermediate container ebdfdd5e3762
Successfully built c175b1fbd2c1
Successfully tagged dshawul/acecast:latest

$ sudo docker run -it dshawul/acecast:latest
[root@9cd1ed4fdf3a /]# cat mybinpath
/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[root@9cd1ed4fdf3a /]# cat mylibpath
/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/lib:
[root@9cd1ed4fdf3a /]# exit
exit

==========================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something else going on in your environment, maybe a cached image, because I cannot reproduce your issue:

```
$ cat df.so-51670836
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-centos7 AS devel
ENV PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/bin:$PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RUN touch mylibpath && \
    touch mybinpath && \
    echo $PATH >> mybinpath && \
    echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH >> mylibpath

$ docker build -t so-51670836 -f df.so-51670836 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.04kB
Step 1/4 : FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-centos7 AS devel
 ---> 96c10ed77499
Step 2/4 : ENV PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in c152383485fd
Removing intermediate container c152383485fd
 ---> c47e029b5e50
Step 3/4 : ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 ---> Running in b58a94b16980
Removing intermediate container b58a94b16980
 ---> 3c02bc748518
Step 4/4 : RUN touch mylibpath &&     touch mybinpath &&     echo $PATH >> mybinpath &&     echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH >> mylibpath
 ---> Running in e81f4e821d28
Removing intermediate container e81f4e821d28
 ---> f5c5c2868350
Successfully built f5c5c2868350
Successfully tagged so-51670836:latest

$ docker run -it --rm so-51670836
[root@dfcb06ce3ac1 /]# cat my
mybinpath  mylibpath
[root@dfcb06ce3ac1 /]# cat mylibpath
/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
[root@dfcb06ce3ac1 /]# cat mybinpath
/opt/pgi/linux86-64/18.4/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[root@dfcb06ce3ac1 /]# exit
exit

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:09:33 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:07:38 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Comment: I have a different version, maybe that is the problem. $ sudo snap refresh --beta docker
docker (beta) 17.09.1-ce from 'docker-inc' refreshed

Comment: Indeed, I upgraded to 18.06 and it suddenly works. It may also be the case that the older 17.09 was working but that caching was messing up with it (had some images) and restarting the service would have worked.

Comment: @danny There are images all over github setting this variable, both old and recent, so I'm doubting the docker version itself did this. But running an old cached image may. That said, you're not the first to see it, but everyone that's reported it hasn't been able to narrow it down or reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Dockerfile` this is easiest if you just install software into directories like `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib` that are already on `$PATH` and in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.  Since you're describing a reproducible build process on something that will run in an isolated filesystem you're not really "contaminating the installed OS".

I've seen [some](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/403) [hints](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/issues/39) [that](https://github.com/docker/docker-snap/issues/30) Docker might be silently stripping, ignoring, or resetting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, though I can't find explicit documentation to that effect.